# Understanding how D3.js binds data to nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

I'm reading through the D3.js documentation, and am finding it hard to understand [the `selection.data` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data) from the documentation.

This is the example code given in the documentation:

```
var matrix = [
  [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868],
  [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171],
  [ 8010, 16145, 8090, 8045],
  [ 1013,   990,  940, 6907]
];

var tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
    .data(matrix)
  .enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("td")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

I understand most of this, but what is going on with the `.data(function(d) { return d; })` section of the `var td` statement?

My best guess is as follows:

- The `var tr` statement has bound a four-element array to each tr node
- The `var td` statement then uses that four-element array as its data, somehow

But how does `.data(function(d) { return d; })` actually get that data, and what does it return?

Comment: It might help to read through [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

Comment: Thanks! I now understand what's going on with the `.enter()` parts of the code. I think I might need to wait for the future tutorial to understand what's going on with the data key function, though.

Comment: I hope to write a new tutorial soon that covers the key function and also hierarchical selections (selectAll.selectAll).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

When you write:

```
….data(someArray).enter().append('foo');
```

D3 creates a bunch of `<foo>` elements, one for each entry in the array. More importantly, it also associates the data for each entry in the array with that DOM element, as a `__data__` property.

Try this:

```
var data = [ {msg:"Hello",cats:42}, {msg:"World",cats:17} ]; 
d3.select("body").selectAll("q").data(data).enter().append("q");
console.log( document.querySelector('q').__data__ );
```

What you will see (in the console) is the object `{msg:"Hello",cats:42}`, since that was associated with the first created `q` element.

If you later do:

```
d3.selectAll('q').data(function(d){
  // stuff
});
```

the value of `d` turns out to be that `__data__` property. (At this point it's up to you to ensure that you replace `// stuff` with code that returns a new array of values.)

[Here's another example](http://phrogz.net/js/d3-playground/#MultiBars_HTML) showing the data bound to the HTML element and the ability to re-bind subsets of data on lower elements:

[image: no description]

Answer (score 23):

The key to understanding what this code is doing is to recognize that selections are *arrays of arrays* of DOM elements. The outer-most array is called a 'selection', the inner array(s) are called 'groups' and those groups contain the DOM elements. You can test this by going into the console at d3js.org and making a selection like d3.selectAll('p'), you will see an array containing an array containing 'p' elements.

In your example, when you first call selectAll('tr') you get a selection with a single group that contains all the 'tr' elements. Then each element of `matrix` is matched to each 'tr' element.

But when you call selectAll('td') on that selection, the selection already contains a group of 'tr' elements. This time each of those elements will each **become a group** of 'td' elements. A group is just an array, but it also has a parentNode property that references the old selection, in this case the 'tr' elements.

Now when you call `data(function(d) { return d; })` on this new selection of 'td' elements, `d` represents the data bound to each group's parent node. So in the example, the 'td's in the first group will be bound with the array [11975,  5871, 8916, 2868]. The second group of 'td's are bound with [ 1951, 10048, 2060, 6171].

You can read mike bostock's own excellent explanation of selections and data binding here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Comment: Thanks! I think this answer is very clear, gets straight to the point; more so than other answer (which also offers useful information, no offence)

Comment: Thanks to the link Kim. Thats detailed enough for me to understand. Further that nudged me to http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

Comment: While Phrogz's comment has some excellent information & is very useful, this answer clearly explains the **exact** question asked.  I had the same confusion, and it clicked when I saw the part that `return d;` returns the **parent** node.  The confusion is that certain methods work at different hierarchical levels.  E.g., `attr` works on the individual elements, unlike `data`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the counter *i* to show the index of the data being used.

```
var tr = d3.select("body").append("table").selectAll("tr")
.data(matrix)
.enter().append("tr") //create a row for each data entry, first index
.text(function(d, i) { return i}); // show the index i.e. d[0][] then d[1][] etc.

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("td")
.style("background-color", "yellow") //show each cell
.text(function(d,i) { return i + " " + d; }); // i.e d[from the tr][0] then d[from the tr][1]...
```