# Collapisible Tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I am a novice in D3Js development. While trying out the tree layout, I am not able to understand the key function that uses d.id. What does id mean and what is the key function here is trying to return ? Please help.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

```
function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481497/understanding-how-d3-js-binds-data-to-nodes) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just do a quick debug for your example:
It seems every time the nodes which will be displayed in the graph will be assigned an id, see debug screenshot for detail:
[image]

hope it helps:)

Comment: Ahhh ok ... I was searching for the id field in the json file. Now I know where to find it. Thanks huan that helps a lot.